# Docker problemas de permisos para modificar un volumen anclado en una carpeta

Tags: docker

Hola estoy usando docker para montar un pequeño entorno de desarrollo para wordpress por que quiero aprender algo sobre Docker. Normalmente uso virtaulHost con apache pero me interesa usar las ventajas que tiene docker(No quiero estar reconfigurando el apache o nginx)

Este el archivo docker-compose.yml que he encontrado en la pagina de docker oficial:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
 #segun entiendo esta es el contenedor de la Base de Datos
 db:
   image: mysql:5.7
   volumes:
   - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
   restart: always
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
     MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
     MYSQL_USER: wordpress
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

 wordpress:
   #Este es dock del wordpress
   depends_on:
     - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
     - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    #Aqui viene los volumenes es decir yo tengo una carpeta que contiene el docker-compose.yml y 2 carpetas donde irian los plugins y los themas
    volumes:
      - ./plugins/:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/:Z # Plugin development
      - ./themes/:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/:Z # Theme development
   environment:
     WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
     WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
     WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
#todavia no entiendo para que es esto
volumes:
   db_data:
```

Lo que pasa es que cuando trado de editar o crear algo en esas carpetas tengo problemas con los permisos. Esto se soluciona rapidamente agregando permisos de la forma tradicional.

Pero me gustaria saber si existe una forma de configurar los permisos desde el docker-compose.yml para que no tenga que usar chmod 777 en las carpetas donde he puesto los themes y los plugins

Comment: puedes intentar con "sudo docker-composer up -d"

Answer (score 0):

Hola he tenido el mismo problema y lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

1ro. antes de iniciar el `$ docker-compose up -d`, crea tu carpeta y coloca los archivos del tema que esta desarrollando.

2do. Ahora ya puedes ejecutar `$ docker-compose up -d`

te dejo un ejemplo:

```
volumes:
  - ./carpeta_de_tu_tema:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/carpeta_de_tu_tema/
```

Docker creara automáticamente la carpeta de tu tema en el contenedor y lo vinculara con el volumen de tu tema.

espero te sirva yo también recién estoy empezando en el mundo de docker.